# Plaid REST API: does selection-based MFA ever expect a scalar value and not an array?

Tags: rest, plaid

From the Plaid documentation:

> Some institutions require the user to answer a question from a limited set of answers, i.e. multiple-choice. Multiple questions may be returned, and the MFA answer submission must be a JSON-encoded array with answers provided in the same order as the given questions.

Based on this, I understand it to mean that:

- If there is only one question in the response array, submit the answer as a scalar value
- If there is more than one question in the response array, submit the answer as an array of values

Is this correct?

For example, if plaid returns:

```
{
    "type": "questions",
    "mfa": [{"question":"What was the name of your first pet?"}],
    "access_token": "xxxxx"
}
```

I would submit:

```
{
    "mfa": "fido"
}
```

But if plaid returns:

```
{
    "type": "questions",
    "mfa": [
        {"question":"What was the name of your first pet?"},
        {"question":"What was the name of your first girlfriend?"}
    ],
    "access_token": "xxxxx"
}
```

I would submit:

```
{
    "mfa": ["fido", "forever alone"]
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Plaid will only send one MFA at a time for the user. I have checked with one of their banks in the sandbox and it sent, then sent another after I answered the first MFA incorrectly.

I don't believe you'll get 2 MFAs in the same JSON object.

I've implemented their MFA scheme like this:

```
public static function accountOrMFA($response, $formBuilder, $formId = null, $request = null) {
    if ($response) {
        // do we have a MFA or the accounts?
        if (property_exists($response, "mfa")) {
            // we have MFA to deal with
            $mfa['type'] = $response->type;
            $mfa['data'] = $response->mfa;
            $mfa['access_token'] = $response->access_token;

            return response()->json(['html' => PlaidController::makeHTMLForMFA($mfa, $formBuilder)]);
        } else {
            $auth_accounts = [];
            $connect_accounts = [];
            foreach($response->accounts as $account) {
                $auth_accounts[] = [
                    'id' => $account->_id,
                    'number' => $account->meta->number,
                    'name' => $account->meta->name,
                    'type' => $account->type,
                ];
            }

            $connect_response = UserController::storeToken($response, $request); // add this token to the user's tokens

            return response()->json(['html' => PlaidController::makeHTMLForAccounts($auth_accounts, $formBuilder, $formId)]);
        }

    }

    return response()->json(['error' => true, 'response' => json_encode($response)]); // maybe the wrong credentials? we don't know
}
```